# How to exclude and lookup the value of RecycleBin in Oracle

Tags: oracle, macos, docker, recycle-bin

When querying constraints in Oracle 11g, execute the following query.

```
SELECT 
                CC.OWNER as "owner"
            ,   CC.TABLE_NAME as "tableName"
            ,   CC.COLUMN_NAME as "columnName"
            ,   CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME as "constraintName"
            ,   CC.POSITION as "position"
    FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS CC 
    WHERE CC.OWNER IN ('<schemaName>')
    ORDER BY CC.POSITION ASC;
```

However, the data in recyclebin is also searched as shown below.
(For reference, the owner in the figure below is the schema name Docker.)

[image]

I'm running on Mac OS Docker. Does it appear because it is a Docker environment?

I don't need this data at all, so I want to check it out.

Any way other than clearing the data in recyclebin with **purge recyclebin** command?

Comment: Can't you just filter out names starting with 'BIN$'?

Comment: Malicious users could do `create table "BIN$HELLO_WORLD" (x int);`) @AlexPoole

Comment: Of course, if they have access to the schema being checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the fact, that [ALL_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_TABLES.html#GUID-6823CD28-0681-468E-950B-966C6F71325D) does *not* return tables that were *dropped*, so a simple *inner join*  on `OWNER, TABLE_NAME` will do the elimination:

```
SELECT 
                CC.OWNER as "owner"
            ,   CC.TABLE_NAME as "tableName"
            ,   CC.COLUMN_NAME as "columnName"
            ,   CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME as "constraintName"
            ,   CC.POSITION as "position"
    FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS CC 
    JOIN ALL_TABLES T on T.OWNER = CC.OWNER and T.TABLE_NAME = CC.TABLE_NAME /* Added line */
    WHERE CC.OWNER IN ('REPORTER')
    ORDER BY CC.POSITION ASC;
```